# Optimal Data Fetching Strategies in Next.js 14: Backend vs. Next.js API Routes vs. ORM (Prisma)

Tags: next.js, orm, prisma

I am currently navigating the intricacies of data fetching in Next.js 14 and seek guidance on selecting the most efficient approach. I'm evaluating the following options:

- Traditional Backend Server with Axios and useEffect:
- Utilizing Next.js API Routes for Backend Operations:
- Leveraging ORM (Prisma) with Server Actions(without the need for an api server)

I am keen to understand the nuanced pros and cons of each approach, considering factors such as development complexity, performance optimization, and long-term maintainability. Your insights and experiences would greatly aid in making an informed decision. Thank you for your expertise.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

- Traditional Backend Server with Axios and useEffect:

Not a good option as you would need to work with CORS if you hit any client components (which happens in most cases)

- Utilizing Next.js API Routes for Backend Operations:

This is my preferred solution. You bypass CORS issues and can use Axios here if you want an external API call. It also helps avoid having some of the config sent to the client (which might help in some cases with security).

On a side note, you can use server action to get the same result ;)

On the down side, it is the most work.

- Leveraging ORM (Prisma) with Server Actions(without the need for an api server)

I don't like it as it would require access to the DB from your web app and, in most cases, this means being stuck with the DB in the same environment as your app (i.e. using Vercel DB if you deploy on Vercel) or opening your DB for internet access which is a security risk (even if you can limit it in most cases)

So I would almost always go for number 2 except in cases where you can use everything in the same environment, in which case, number 3 is faster to develop. But I would never use number 1.